# How to enconde this

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I just need to encode this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\666\Desktop\New folder (8)\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
```

> DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51491/devtools/browser/c511792d-8eba-498d-a312-9fd837f06a64

```
url = 'https://www.milversite.club/milver/outsiders-1x01-video_060893d7a.html'
driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
print (iframe)("utf-8")
```

out=>

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3d2a99626133163845c0bfbcc2a3bf1c", element="0.45589168341957964-1")>]
```

How to get the link inside `[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3d2a99626133163845c0bfbcc2a3bf1c", element="0.45589168341957964-1")>]`

Comment: Where have you invoked `get()` passing the _url_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must start with : `get(url)`

Then you can print all the HTML code with:

```
html_source = driver.page_source
print(html_source)
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Yeah that helped me! :) Thank you
Can you just tell me, how to extract now the: src="" ? if u could that would be nice <3

Comment: Glad to help!!! In order to get any attribute (such as `src`) you use the `get_attribute()` function in your case `html_source.get_attribute("src")` I think that should do the trick!!!
I am on mobile now so I can't check it...

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work... Can i conntact you somewhere ?

Comment: Email me... moshes@avratech.org.il